# How ASP.NET 4 validation controls work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I create new page with lots of validation controls, such as RequiredValidation, RegexValidation and so on. I found out that when I create these validation controls, it seems like it render both client java-script and server validation for me automatically.

I want to know, do I understand correctly or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. That is correct. The built-in controls do server side validation (for security) and client side validation (for performance and user experience) for you.

Tip: Don't add these validations to the mark-up, but add them through the code behind, as shown in this [blog post](http://blog.devshed.nl/2011/01/aspnet-compile-time-supported_06.html), since it keeps your code DRY.

Comment: Do you mean don't use Validation controls in .aspx file but use them in .aspx.cs?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Comment: I would also suggest making use of Data Annotations for validation. Check out this Blog post for how to do it http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/08/aspnet-webforms-validation-with-data.html It not only keeps your .aspx page DRY but opens up for scalability

Comment: I agree with Tim. If you can, use VAB or DataAnnotations. [Here is a post](http://adventuresdotnet.blogspot.com/2009/08/aspnet-webforms-validation-with-data.html) about doing DataAnnotations with web forms, bug instead of adding the `DataAnnotationValidator` in markup, use extension methods in the code behind. [Here's an example](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=78) of how to do that with VAB. The idea with DataAnnotations is the same.

Comment: @Steven: do you mean VAB in Enterprise Library? It seems like there're lots of things I need to learn. :)

Comment: @Anonymous: My apologies. Yes I mean the Enterprise Library Validation Application Block.